# If the product of two numbers is positive and less than one, what can I conclude about the quotient?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If I'm given that $0 < ab < 1$, how do I figure out what values $\frac ab$ can take on?

I have $0 < ab < 1$ and am asked if $\frac ab < 1$.

I can see that if I set $a = \frac 12$ and $b = \frac 14$, then $ab = 0.125$ but $\frac ab = 2$, so the answer is no, but I'm wondering if there is some systematic way to demonstrate this? Or if plugging in values *is* the best way to do this, is there some systematic way to choose the values to plug in?

I don't know everything I should be considering, and can easily see myself trying the few things that pop into my head, then drawing an erroneous conclusion because I wasn't considering some important class of options.

Comment: You can abstract plugging in values. For any $c > 0$, you have $(ca)\left(\frac{b}{c}\right) = ab$, but $\frac{ca}{b/c} = c^2\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case a little trial and error is quite likely to lead one rather quickly to an example like yours. Alternatively, one might quickly realize that if $0<b<a<1$, then $0<ab<1$ and $\frac{a}b>1$, thereby obviating the need for a specific example. The real insight there is that if $a,b>0$ and $a\ne b$, then one of $\frac{a}b$ and $\frac{b}a$ **must** be greater than $1$, regardless of what $ab$ is.

Comment: @dumbquestion: You can’t conclude that $b<a$ from what you’re given. The point is that what you’re given **allows** $b$ to be less than $a$ and therefore does not imply that $\frac{a}b<1$. It also does not imply that $\frac{a}b>1$ or that $\frac{a}b=1$; all of these are consistent with the hypothesis that $0<ab<1$, which therefore does not imply any of them.